# Is it possible to use string literals in process.env values?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, dotenv

I would like to add an environment variables with parameters.
something like:

```
URL= https://my-domain.com/test/${value}?code=7NqsdKgBKw
```

and calculate the value in js.

```
const value = Math.random();
fetch(process.env.URL);
```

how can I get the same effect as using literals?

```
const value = Math.random();
fetch(`https://my-domain.com/test/${value}?code=7NqsdKgBKw`);
```

Comment: Is this Node.js? I’m assuming so because of `process.env`, but it seems good to make sure. :)

Comment: this is react, but your answer works well also in browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cases that are simple enough (no escaping, only one variable), Node.js has a built-in [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) with printf-style placeholders that’s nice and light:

```
URL=https://my-domain.com/test/%s?code=7NqsdKgBKw
```

```js
// ESM: import { format } from 'util';
const { format } = require('util');

const urlFormat = process.env.URL;

const value = Math.random();

fetch(format(urlFormat, value))
```